# Is it possible to make ComposeKey sequences visible like Ctrl+Shift+U?

Tags: compose-key

So `.XCompose` gives us a way to create custom compose sequences, however is it possible to make the input of these sequences visible in the same way that when using Ctrl+Shift+U shows `u<HexDigits>` while typing the input?

i.e. When using Ctrl+Shift+U you see the escape sequence while it is typed:

[image: Like this:]

Can we do the same for `.XCompose` bindings so that if I have some sequence, say `<Multi_key> <a> <b> <c>` that when typing that sequence I would see some similar visuals while composing the sequence?

Comment: Could you add your Ubuntu Version since your question relies on the X-11 server. With the latest Ubuntu, wayland is default...

Comment: 20.04 Although I tried out the latest version, and it seems to just work out of the box so that'll do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not as a normal user. It would require delving into the system code to implement such feature.